# Solving the SDE $\mathrm dX_t=\frac1{X_t}\,\mathrm dt+kX_t\,\mathrm d{X_t}$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm looking to solve the stochastic differential equation
$$\mathrm dX_t=\frac1{X_t}\,\mathrm dt+kX_t\,\mathrm d{W_t},$$
where $k\in\mathbb R$ is a constant. I am quite certain that I will need to substitute something along the lines $X_t\exp\,(\cdots)$ and possibly prove $X_t>0$ a.s. (perhaps via $X_t\exp\,(\cdots)>0$ a.s.) but I haven't been able to come up with a successful substitution to do so. Could someone provide some guidance please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us denote $Y_t = X_t^2$, using Ito' lemma, we deduce easily that
$$dY_t = Y_t (k^2dt+2kdW_t) + 2dt \tag{1}$$

The equation $(1)$ is a special case of the equation
$$dY_t =Y_t(b(t)dt +\sigma(t)dW_t)+c(t)+\delta(t)dW_t \tag{2}$$
with

- $b(t)=k^2$
- $\sigma(t) = 2k$
- $c(t) = 2$
- $\delta(t)=0$

The solution of $(2)$ is
$$Y_t = Z_t\left(Y_0+\int_0^t  \frac{c(s)-\sigma(s)\delta(s)}{Z_s}ds +\int_0^t\frac{\delta(s)}{Z_s}ds   \right)$$
with
$$Z_t :=\exp{\left(\int_0^t b(s)ds +\int_0^t \sigma(s)dW_s -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma^2(s)ds  \right)}$$

The solution of $(1)$ seems to be
$$Y_t = e^{-k^2 t + 2kW_t}  \left(Y_0 + 2\int_0^t e^{k^2 s - 2kW_s} ds  \right)$$

Q.E.D

Comment: The $2$ in the last line should be outside the parenthesis?

Comment: @Snoop: Yes, in fact  $$Y_t = e^{-k^2 t + 2kW_t}  \left(Y_0 + \int_0^t \frac{2}{e^{-k^2 s + 2kW_s}}  ds  \right)$$

Comment: @NN2 Hi, how did you know to substitute $Y=X^2$? Is there a name for equation (2), and what makes it so special?

Comment: @Snoop If you multiplie the two members of the initial equation by $X$, you get $$XdX = ...dt + X^2dW_t$$ That's why I substitute $Y = X^2$. About the equation $(2)$, perhaps it may be called linear stochastic equation? It's a most general linear stochastic equation that has closed form solution. (the detail proof I found is not written in English)